# Not able to connect to server through java code. Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, rest, ssl, rest-assured, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to build a Test Automation Tool for REST API on AWS using **rest-assured** framework. I just tried with a simple HTTP POST and checking the output JSON body. But when I run that in Eclipse I get **SSLHandshakeException**. I did try to look into the issue and found it could be something related to server certificate ([Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)) but when I test it through POSTMAN it is running fine and gives desired output. Also if I hit the URI through the browser does gets the response from the server(Error message). I am novice to SSL programming and will like to know what could be the root cause behind it and how I can fix that and proceed.

Here is the code snippet for my test method.

```
    public class First {


      @Test
      public void myFirstRestAssuredTest()
      {



            given().header("content-type", "application/json").and().header("cache-control", "no-cache").expect().body("messageType", equalTo("XYZ")).when().post(https://my-server-address.com/postUpdate");



     }
 }
```

This is the stack trace I am getting :

```
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2028)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:349)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1631)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1637)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:170)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at restassuredtest.First.myFirstRestAssuredTest(First.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Logs after adding certificates in caserts file.

```
    trigger seeding of SecureRandom
    done seeding SecureRandom
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1465583840 bytes = { 89, 209, 72, 175, 175, 187, 136, 39, 217, 133, 241, 84, 37, 130, 134, 92, 132, 179, 147, 40, 230, 111, 93, 56, 71, 15, 75, 197 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 193
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

**Update 6/14/2016**

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect my_server_name.amazonaws.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.amazon.com -CAfile aws3.pem
CONNECTED(0000016C)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = "Amazon.com, Inc.", CN = *.cloudfront.net
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.cloudfront.net
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.cloudfront.net
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3284 bytes and written 356 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: EE111BD2FFFE75AF719AD48D6D07D2CBB1A9B078CE8CF9F1E47D3CE0D9F8CF86
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 507ADD06A6B1729AD4B0441AB124C7F2CE5FD492B08527CE5FFE62DAE7B0FF7A6EE8D53401978BAAC75F62FBA1F289D5
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 10800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c5 40 de d4 76 bc 79 07-a4 87 5f 8d 99 38 c8 92   .@..v.y..._..8..
    0010 - e5 b0 b4 b3 f1 b6 92 18-d6 d8 94 18 56 27 fa de   ............V'..
    0020 - 0d 7b 8a ac e0 f7 7e 68-c5 7e a4 7e 73 78 b0 45   .{....~h.~.~sx.E
    0030 - 06 70 10 34 54 37 ce ff-01 d5 62 20 2a b9 2e 7d   .p.4T7....b *..}
    0040 - 9e 24 72 a9 b7 37 54 d5-1c 0e 9e 63 84 1f 09 2c   .$r..7T....c...,
    0050 - c6 4c 44 c5 f2 ea 07 23-40 a1 38 d4 d5 77 c8 4a   .LD....#@.8..w.J
    0060 - 12 3f b1 91 7c e0 40 07-3f 66 bf 3c 30 02 d6 a5   .?..|.@.?f.<0...
    0070 - 9e 46 f8 97 27 c7 35 9f-44 9d 7b 93 66 ea 02 a8   .F..'.5.D.{.f...
    0080 - 32 ec b0 4d 56 6d eb 77-22 df da e9 63 64 f3 70   2..MVm.w"...cd.p
    0090 - 2e af 52 c8 c9 89 6e 37-63 5a b2 d1 ca ea 9a 43   ..R...n7cZ.....C
    00a0 - 16 e5 7b f0 f6 dc 10 9a-20 06 fe c8 c7 9f 24 12   ..{..... .....$.

    Start Time: 1465936365
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Received fatal alert: handshake\_failure through SSLHandshakeException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

Comment: FYI: the openssl command did TLSv1(.0) because you _specified_ `-tls1`; if you leave that out and let openssl negotiate you would have gotten 1.2. But that probably doesn't matter; the problem was probably lack of SNI (see my comment on pedrofb's answer) and that is independent of protocol version. You can test that (or could have) by omitting the `-servername host` from `s_client` and see if that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am new to rest-assured, but the java SSL problems like `handshake_failure` are usually the same:

- Incompatible cipher suites: The client has to use a cipher suite enabled by the server
- Incompatible versions of SSL/TLS: The client have to ensure that it uses a compatible version. For example the server might force TLS1.2 that is not enabled by default in java7
- Incomplete trust path for the server certificate: the server certificate  is probably not trusted by the client. Usually the fix is to import the server certificate chain in into the client trust store.
- Bad server config, like certificate issued to a different domain or certificate chain incomplete. In the case the fix is on server part

To detect the cause the following environment variable can be set to verbose the protocol details

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

For your specific issue with SSL, take a look at rest assured ssl documentation https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#ssl

First you can try to disable usual https verification

```
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().get("https://some_server.com"). ..
```

If it works, create a JKS truststore with the certificates of the server

1)Download them from the server (click on browser green lock and download each one)
2) Create the JKS with keytool and import the trusted certificates. Follow the  [guide](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/SSL) in rest-assured guide or use [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net)
3) Configure truststore in JKS

```
given().keystore("/pathToJksInClassPath", <password>). ..
```

If you need client authentication ( I think no), check this post [How to make HTTPS GET call with certificate in Rest-Assured java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352033/how-to-make-https-get-call-with-certificate-in-rest-assured-java/37422468#37422468)

If nothing of this works for you, do not forget todebug the SSL connection with

```
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

Ensure that the algorithm of your server is supported by your client. For example if you use Java7, TLS1.2 is not enabled by default

Comment: I tried the above steps but still I am not able to proceed. For your last point I did checked about TLS1.2 compatibility it is defualt for Java 1.8 [link]( https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls ).  Also, after debugging the SSL connection it shows the certificates I have added into the cacerts file but still its gives handshake exception. Can you think of something else for this issue?

Comment: Check your server with SSLlabs looking for errors and supported config. Also you could attach the ssl debug log so we can take a look

Comment: I have added the logs in my original post. The logs are after the trusted certs details.

Comment: You checked the server with SSLLabs?

Comment: Ya I did that. Any specific thing I should check in SSLLabs for my server?

Comment: Look for issues with certificate or chain. Ensure all is 'green'. Tlsv1.2 enabled. I can not set anything at logs. The handshake is using tlsv1.2? Check if client cipher suite is compatible wih server cipher suite

Comment: This is what I got now when I ran again : Chain issues None , Protocols
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3 No
SSL 2 No,  Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure for - IE 6/XP, IE 8/XP, Java 6u45

Comment: For Java8 details in SSLLabs, under Protocol details there is **NO** for **SSL 2 handshake compatibility**.

Comment: Except handshake_failure for java6, everything is normal. One additional check. ¿Are you using the unlimited security policy of java 8? You have to download and install. This will unlock additional ciphers. Please install it, debug the CLIENT HELLO and SERVER HELLO, and be aware about the cipher list sent by the client, the list received from server, and check that are at least one in common

Comment: Just tried with installing security policy for java 8 but still the same case/ Getting same exception!!

Comment: Can it be something from the server side? I just tried to make a connection without REST Assured from Java using simple URL and HttpsURLConnection and I got 403 - forbidden. But it does work using POSTMAN. Still can there be some parameters which need to be set from the server?

Comment: a 403 is a code returned by server **after handshake**, so it could be a bad configuration of rest-assured. It means that server is working propertly.  I suggest build a fully functional java example without rest-assured, debug the ssl connection and check differences: protocol, ciphers and keystore to fix the problem

Comment: I tried a fully functional example using Apache HTTPClient and it is working fine with that and on comparing logs with rest assured one it has same protocol and ciphers and I have already added the keystore earlier. I also tried getting details using openSSL Client. I have added that in my original post. openSSL shows Protocol as TLSv1 but logs in Java shows TLSv1.2 but [TLSv1.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls) is backward compatible, so that won't be a problem I guess

Comment: Maybe a bug?. It is possibe for you updating to newest versión or downgrade to latest stable? In this forum they also suggest use relaxedHTTPconfig or define your own sslsocketfactory https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/rest-assured/68MtRdXgoSg

Comment: I just came to post the same link, that it may be a bug in REST assured itself but you already posted the same link.. :) .. Also the workaround given in this forum seems obsolete and doesn't work with latest version. I need to check with earlier version though if it works.

Comment: Also there is this latest [conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rest-assured/handshake/rest-assured/kHKf04XH6yA/mIcnO0jyBAAJ) about the issue.

Comment: Your bullets 3 and 4 (server cert issues) can cause failure of SSL/TLS handshake and SSLHandshakeException, but never the specific failure in this Q = "received fatal alert: handshake_failure". **Another possibility,** common since just about 2016 and **especially for shared hosting** like AWS/Cloudfront, is that the server requires **SNI** (ServerNameIndication) in ClientHello and the client didn't send it, which depends on Java version and code used, confirmed here by the posted debuglog. OTOH that googrope link is for "Path building failed" which _is_ a cert issue.

Comment: Did you resolved it at the end? Information about resolution would be very useful to others

Comment: Adding relaxedHTTPSValidation() helped to remove SSLHandshakeException

Answer (score 10):

Try overriding the apache HTTP Client version--upgrading it to 4.5.3 in my pom.xml file fixed it for me.

Comment: Also worked for me. Does not require relaxedHTTPSValidation either.

Comment: Thanks.. this worked for me!!! This is the dependency that I added, <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Yep - this rest-assured SSLHandshakeException issue seems related to a bug or unexpected behavior from httpclient 4.5.2. Can also confirm overriding with 4.5.3 resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible explanations:

- Your local java security not able to trust the target. Import target public
  cert as trusted entry.
- SSL version of target could be different from default outboud SSL
  version your JVM is choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Answer (score 0):

As this is a highly active question and amazon support tends to link this question as a standard reply -  adding `jdk.crypto.cryptoki` (through `jlink`) and  `ca-certificates` to the docker files fixed the issue - in case you are using java. The TLS version was 1.2 and seems the problem was related to the older versions of amazon sdk.