# Getting SSLHandShakeException in Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, ssl, rest-assured

I am trying to import certificate from Rest Assured but always getting SSLHandShakeException error. These are the steps which I performed.

1. Download the certificate from the site in .cer format.
2. Converted the .cer file to .jks format
3. Trying the below code to import it from Rest Assured.

   ```
   RestAssured.trustStore("C:/Test/KeyStoreN.jks", password);
   RestAssured.given().when().get("https://XXXX").then()
   ```

But getting the SSLHandShakeException while running the code. I tried the solution mentioned in [How to make HTTPS GET call with certificate in Rest-Assured java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352033/how-to-make-https-get-call-with-certificate-in-rest-assured-java) but it is not working. Also the solution provided in the [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore) requires changes to be made in the cacerts file which could be difficult in my case as I don't have the required permission to change anything in the machine.

Please suggest ? Thanks

Here is the stack trace

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:492)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:441)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1396)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1178)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:160)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at com.americanexpress.travel.grm.businesslogic.api.Admin.testGetMarketList(Admin.java:68)
at com.americanexpress.travel.grm.testscripts.api.TestAdminAPI.getMarketList(TestAdminAPI.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:230)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
... 116 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 122 more
```

Comment: Stack trace and complete error message please.

Comment: Added the details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the question but that solution requires adding keystore in the cacerts file. That solution may not work in our case as we need to run the execution from Jenkins and we don't have the permission to change anything in Jenkins server.

Any other solution through which I can run the code ?

Comment: If the server certificate is self-signed you either have to import it into your truststore or get it signed by a CA, which is much the better solution anyway. Self-signed certificates are far more trouble than they are worth, and they are only worth the money you pay for them, which is zero. There is a third solution but it is radically insecure and I won't mention it here.

Comment: Call the static method on RestAssured, useRelaxedHttpsValidation.