# SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target , where is the .cer file

Tags: api, rest, curl, postman, rest-assured

If I fire this curl command in CMD or POSTMAN it gives me correct results but when I run it with `RestAssured` it is giving me below error.

```
curl -X GET "https://staging.demo.com/mnt_rostr/api/v1/mnt_employees" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "x-ww-api-token: sgsgshdhhfhf45745675674fhdhfgjjf"
```

**Error**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2146)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451)
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1544)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1749)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1755)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:171)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.example.utils.ApiUtil.getAPIResponse(ApiUtil.java:82)
    at org.example.TestOne.printValues(TestOne.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityStatement.evaluate(SerenityStatement.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.performRunChild(SerenityRunner.java:467)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(SerenityRunner.java:441)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(SerenityRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.run(SerenityRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityParameterizedRunner.run(SerenityParameterizedRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 147 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 153 more

[main] ERROR  - 
  _____   ___   ___   _____     ___   ___   ___    ___    ___ 
 |_   _| | __| / __| |_   _|   | __| | _ \ | _ \  / _ \  | _ \
   | |   | _|  \__ \   | |     | _|  |   / |   / | (_) | |   /
   |_|   |___| |___/   |_|     |___| |_|_\ |_|_\  \___/  |_|_\

Print values
---------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR  -     PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome - SetUserStory Test one
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.model.TestOutcome - SetUserStory Test one
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService - net.thucydides.core.reports.json.JSONTestOutcomeReporter@22eaa86e: Generating report for test outcome: Test one:printValues
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService - net.thucydides.core.reports.html.HtmlAcceptanceTestReporter@561b7d53: Generating report for test outcome: Test one:printValues

Process finished with exit code -1
```

What I tried:

1. Update the java version to latest
2. Trying solution on this post ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)
   But I don't know where to get the `.cer` file.

**I am using:**

1. Windows 10
2. java version "1.8.0_311"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Did you try `RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();`?

Comment: I don't want to ignore it, Lucas. Is there a way I can use **with** HTTPS? –

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352033/how-to-make-https-get-call-with-certificate-in-rest-assured-java