# RestAssured API call failed due to SSL handshake issue

Tags: java, ssl, rest-assured

I need to run my rest-assured automated tests on an environment that don't have SSL certificate, the test failed at the first call with the following exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
```

I updated the code to use the following specifications:
first I tried

```
    public static void addHeadersToRequestsSpecifications(Map<String, String> authHeaders, String cookieValue) {
    API.addRequestSpec(new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setConfig(RestAssuredConfig.newConfig().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation()))
            .addHeader("cookie", cookieValue)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
            .addHeader(TOKEN, authHeaders.get(this.token))
            .addFilter(new AllureRestAssured())
            .build());
}
```

and then I tried:

```
 public static void addHeadersToRequestsSpecifications(Map<String, String> authHeaders, String cookieValue) {
    API.addRequestSpec(new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setConfig(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames()))
            .addHeader("cookie", cookieValue)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
            .addHeader(TOKEN, authHeaders.get(this.token))
            .addFilter(new AllureRestAssured())
            .build());
}
```

in both cases the same error still reproduces, how can I disable SSL verification?

Im using Java version: 17.0.4

rest-assured version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `relaxedHTTPSValidation()` option which just disables the ssl verification. Example code would be:

```java
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().post("https://my_server.com")
```

See also this answer posted on for a similar question: [How to make HTTPS GET call with certificate in Rest-Assured java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011747/6777695)