How to add client certificate (.pfx or .cer + .key) in API-request in Java (Rest assured)
I'm trying to write my first autotests in Java + Rest Assured.
Unfortunately, one of the modules I'm working with requires a client certificate for correct request :) I have the certificate source in .pfx format, as well as .cer (+.key), pem.
In Postman to send the request to this module correctly I am attaching:

Either a .pfx file with a passphrase: e.g. 123456;
Either .cer file + .key file. Passphrase can be omitted in this case.

After that the request is executed (in Postman) correctly.
My question is: HOW can I achieve the same using Java and Rest assured? My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA.
I have tried almost all the variants given by the search. But they describe either loading server certificates into the storage or sending client certificates in the code, but without key / passphrase.
relaxedHTTPSValidation isn't work for me :)
I'm assuming what I need:

Either pre-convert the certificates to another format (keytool or openssl) and then send in the code;
Or maybe it is possible to send the .cer file and the .key file at once without conversion.

Please, help :) Code of my test. Right now I'm getting a 403 error. The same code works in a module that does not require a client certificate.
package com.example.checks;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


import static io.restassured.RestAssured.config;


public class authorizeCustomerTests {

    @Test
    public void authorizeCustomerShouldReturn200(){


        String xmlRequestBody = "xmlBodyofMyRequest";

        RequestSpecification requestSpec = RestAssured.given();

        requestSpec.baseUri("uriOfMyService");
        requestSpec.basePath("pathOfMyService");

        requestSpec.header("Header1", "valueOfHeader1");
        requestSpec.header("Header2", "valueOfHeader2");


        requestSpec.body(xmlRequestBody);

        Response response = requestSpec.post();


        response.prettyPrint();

        Assertions.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200, "Check for status code");


    }
}


Isn’t this a duplicated question? Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36352033/5078874

Yup, i saw this question and recommendations, but isn't work for me. Like i said before, relaxedHTTPSValidation is not my variant. As to the second option from this question, unfortunately my IDE does not recognise the "password" keyword in the code provided. So i don't know, how to launch this example. Third variant is also unsuitable, because my question is not about cacerts. My question is about correctly creating truststore and keystore and passing them in java code. Or, perhaps, only passing the certificate file and key file in Java code

I finally found a solution to my problem.
Firstly, you need to turn your pfx certificate into a JKS file. To do this, use the command line and the keytool utility:
cd C:/Path/To/Folder/With/Your/Pfx

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore NameOfYourPfxCertificate.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore NameOfYourJksKeyStore.jks -deststoretype JKS

In my case you need not only to correctly pass the client JKS-certificate in the code, but also to trust all hosts with their servers certificates (relaxedHTTPSValidation). This allowed us to avoid the 403 error.
The final code looks like this. The main solution of the problem is contained in try and catch blocks.
package com.example.authorizeCustomer;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import io.restassured.config.SSLConfig;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseBody;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class authorizeCustomer3 {

    @Test
    public void authorizeCustomer(){


        String xmlRequestBody = "xmlBodyofMyRequest";

        RequestSpecification requestSpec = RestAssured.given();
    

        requestSpec.baseUri("uriOfMyService");
        requestSpec.basePath("pathOfMyService");

        requestSpec.header("Header1", "valueOfHeader1");
        requestSpec.header("Header2", "valueOfHeader2");
        requestSpec.body(xmlRequestBody);

        try {
                 Response response = requestSpec.config(RestAssuredConfig
                        .config()
                        .sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig()
                                .keyStore("path to jks-file",
                                        "passwordOfKeystore")
                                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                                .and()
                                .allowAllHostnames()))
                .when()
                .post();
        response.prettyPrint();

        Assertions.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200, "Check for status code");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

